# Conditions that the probability density function of a R.V exists

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Given a random variable $X$, we know that its distribution function $F_X$ exists. But its density function $f_X$ may not exist. I am thinking about conditions that allow $f_X$ to exist.

From the definition, a R.V. $X$ has a pdf $f_X$ if and only if $F_X$ can be expressed as
$$F_X(a) = \int_{-\infty}^a f_X(x)dx ~ ~ ~ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}.$$

From measure theory, a monotone increasing function $F_X$ can be written as an indefinite integral like above, if and only if $F_X$ is absolutely continuous. (Or equivalently, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_F$ generated from $F_X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.)

Can I understand that the condition that $f_X$ exists is that its corresponding distribution function $F_X$ must be absolutely continuous?

Comment: Yes, it is a standard fact that $X$ has  a denisty iff $F_X$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. In particular, a mere continuity of $F_X$ does not ensure the existence of a density function, such as in the case of Cantor's distribution (or in general, singular distributions). This is one reason I do not like the term 'continuous distribution'.

Answer (score 1):

It's well known Radon–Nikodym theorem and can be found in Halmos P.R. "Measure Theory" 128p, or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem):

Given $(X, S, \mu)$ $\sigma$-finite measure space and $\sigma$-finite signed measure $\nu$ absolute continuous with respect to $\mu$, then exists measurable $f$, such that
$$\nu(E)=\int\limits_{E}fd\mu$$
for every measurable set $E$.